# Where by month in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, where-clause

I have this code

```
$where = array('MONTH(c.cashDate)' => 'MONTH(NOW())');
$data['dataCash'] = $this->cash->cashList($where);
```

but it doesn't work, its create query like this

```
SELECT `c`.`cashId`, `c`.`cashDescription`, `c`.`cashDate`, `c`.`cashCategory`, `a`.`category`, `c`.`cashValue`, `t`.`typeid`, `t`.`type` FROM (`cash` c) LEFT JOIN `cashCategory` a ON `c`.`cashCategory` = `a`.`categoryId` LEFT JOIN `type` t ON `a`.`type` = `t`.`typeid` WHERE MONTH(c.cashDatee) = 'MONTH(NOW())' ORDER BY `c`.`cashDate` desc
```

when I try with phpmyadmin, it doesnt have a row
but when I remove ' from MONTH(NOW()) like this

```
SELECT `c`.`cashId`, `c`.`cashDescription`, `c`.`cashDate`, `c`.`cashCategory`, `a`.`category`, `c`.`cashValue`, `t`.`typeid`, `t`.`type` FROM (`cash` c) LEFT JOIN `cashCategory` a ON `c`.`cashCategory` = `a`.`categoryId` LEFT JOIN `type` t ON `a`.`type` = `t`.`typeid` WHERE MONTH(c.cashDatee) = MONTH(NOW()) ORDER BY `c`.`cashDate` desc
```

it works, how I call func in controller?
when you do this, it wont work

```
$where = array('MONTH(c.cashDate)' => MONTH(NOW()));
```

Comment: Try `$where = 'MONTH(c.cashDate) = MONTH(NOW())'` and post your model's code too @yudijohn

Comment: yes dude, it's work, thanks, it's cool
btw, it can't done with array?

Comment: Yes it can but need to check that way I thought it to be simplest way. And if this solved your problem then I'm submitting it as an answer and you can accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your `$where` condition

```
$where = array('MONTH(c.cashDate)' => 'MONTH(NOW())');
```

into

```
$where = 'MONTH(c.cashDate) = MONTH(NOW())';
```